# How to make Custom popup look when send Intent in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I`m new to android, I want to look like this [custom popup intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqwKR.jpg)

this is what I get [my popup intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDxhr.jpg)

here my question is how to add custom image and text in above popup when i try to share something via intent send.

this is my code what should I change here?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    "Intall COC!!"+"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your android version it's only supported start at android 11

use below code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here you can make custom title");
            String shareMessage= "\nhere you can make custom message";
            shareMessage = shareMessage + "Intall CoC!!\"+\"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"\n";
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
```

Comment: mine 30 still not getting this option, it works in Android SDK 30 (or higher).